# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$ which have the same characteristic and minimal polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

> Let $A, B$ be two $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$ and $A,B$ have the same characteristic and minimal polynomials. If no eigenvalue has algebraic multiplicity greater than $3,$ then $A$ and $B$ are similar (characteristic polynomial of $A,B$ is $f = (x - c_1)^{d_1} \cdots (x - c_k)^{d_k}$).

I have to use the following result.

> If $A, B$ are two $3 \times 3$ nilpotent matrices. Then $A, B$ are similar if and only if they have same minimal polynomial.

My attempt has been to consider the following cases $ d_i = 1,2,3$ and then the corresponding jordan blocks which becomes same in both the cases. Since two matrices having the same rational form are similar, matrices $A,B$ are similar. My doubt here lies in the fact that where do I need to use the theorem that two $3 \times 3$ nilpotent matrices are similar iff they have the same minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** First you can show that there is a decomposition of $F^n$ such that

$$F^n = \bigoplus_i \ker (A-\lambda_iI)^{d_i}\,.$$

What can you say about $\dim\ker (A-\lambda_iI)^3$ for a given $i$ ? How does $A-\lambda_i I$ act on this subspace?

**Edit:** You are right that using the Jordan form completely trivializes this result. However this result is much easier than Jordan form. In fact you could use a slight generalization of it to prove the existence and unicity of the Jordan form. The above hint gives clues for using the theorem about nilpotent matrices to prove the result.

Comment: $(A-c_iI)$ and $(B-c_i.I)$ have the same minimal and cp but their domains are different.How can I use the theorem to claim that they are similar?

Comment: What do you mean their domains are different?